# Android httpurlconnection can not post bigsize json data

Tags: android, json

In my Android Project I want to post bigsize json data..So, I have used

```
String url1 = localhost://8080/myproject/sendData;
// initialize URL
URL url = new URL(url1);
String urlParameters = "myobject="
        + URLEncoder.encode(jsonobject, "UTF-8");
// instantiate a HttpURLConnection
HttpsURLConnection conn = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
conn.setDoOutput(true);
// sending data as POST
conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
// set the length of the files
conn.setFixedLengthStreamingMode(urlParameters.getBytes().length);
// set headers
conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type",
        "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
conn.setRequestProperty("My-Id", Id);
conn.setDoInput(true);

PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(conn.getOutputStream());
out.print(urlParameters);
out.close();
```

In this code **urlParameters** I'm sending json data..but the problem is if json data is small then it is working..but big size json data is not working..why??

Comment: It will never work as `String url1 = localhost://8080/myproject/sendData;` is no valid url.

Comment: Small? Big? How many bytes?

Comment: Define 'not working' please.